# How do I configure commit hooks in Phabricator that match the current user against a ref name?

Tags: phabricator

In Herald, I can create a rule like this:

```
When [all] of these conditions are met:
  - [Ref type] [is] [branch]
  - [Ref name] [is] [...]
  - [Ref change type] [has bit] [dangerous change]
Take these actions every time this rule matches:
  - [Block push with message] [...]
```

This allows me to block dangerous changes (i.e. `push -f`) on a per-branch basis. A similar rule allows me to prevent new branches from being created on the server.

I'd like to make rules to do the following (using `bob` as an example user):

1. Let user `bob` perform dangerous changes on `bob/*`
2. Let user `bob` create branches `bob/*`

The most natural way to do this would be if I could have a condition like this:

`[Ref name] [matches regexp] [^${PUSH_USER}/]`

I can't find any documentation indicating variables like this exist, so is there some other way to accomplish these goals?

Comment: Seems that you have to create different rules for different users. Such as: `Ref name matches regexp @bob/.*@` and `Pusher is bob`.

Comment: @Landys That wouldn't be so bad if there's a way to create those automatically on user creation (or user being added to a project?). I sort of doubt that's a built-in feature, either, unfortunately.